# Calculate the distances of the values of a matrix to a target matrix Numpy vectorization

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to understand if the following problem can be done with Numpy vectorization.

Assuming a given initial matrix of:

```
7 2 4
5 0 6
8 3 1
```

The aim is to calculate the distance of those elements to the goal matrix consisting of:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The solution would be:

```
3 1 2
2 2 3   
2 2 3
```

Can this be done without iterating over the hole matrix for each element? And, if yes, how?

Some code to get started quick:

```py
import numpy as np
initial_state = np.array([[7, 2, 4], [5, 0, 6], [8, 3, 1]])
goal_state = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
```

**Non-abstracted Context:**

This will be used to write a 8x8 puzzle solver, you might remember this from your childhood:
[image: 8x8 puzzle example]

Comment: Note that "SIMD vector processing" and "Numpy vectorization" are two different things. While the latter can take benefit from the former, it is not always the case. The former is related to your harware/processor, while the latter is related to the Numpy software calls. I highly doubt this operation can be optimized using low-level SIMD vector processing, but it might be vectorized using Numpy. Furthermore, what is the distance used here? Is it the Manhattan distance? Please tell us more about this.

Comment: Thx Jérôme, I've changed the question to reflect your input.

Comment: Are the values always unique integers between `0` and `n*m-1` (included) with `(m,n)` the size of the matrix?

Comment: @JérômeRichard well yes, but only because I've decided to abstract it that way.  0 theoretically could be also of type `None` if that would simplify the case. I've added a picture to better understand the context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution consists in:

- using "flattened" positions to encode the location `(i,j)` in a number `i*m+j` for a matrix of size `(n,m)`;
- putting the positions of both the `initial_state` and `goal_state` matrix in matrices of positions that can be compared latter (so the location of the value 7 in the `initial_state` matrix match with the location of the same value in `goal_state`);
- decoding the flattened positions using modulus/division;
- compute the Manhattan distance between the 2 position matrices;
- putting the distance in the good position regarding the values in `initial_state`.

Here is how to do this with vectorized Numpy operations:

```py
n, m = initial_state.shape

# Build the position matrix for initial_state
initPos = np.empty(n*m, dtype=np.int)
initPos[initial_state.reshape(n*m)] = np.arange(n*m, dtype=np.int)

# Build the position matrix for goal_state
goalPos = np.empty(n*m, dtype=np.int)
goalPos[goal_state.reshape(n*m)] = np.arange(n*m, dtype=np.int)

# Compute the Manhattan distance between the 2 position matrix
xInitPos, yInitPos = initPos%m, initPos//m
xGoalPos, yGoalPos = goalPos%m, goalPos//m
distance = np.abs(xInitPos-xGoalPos) + np.abs(yInitPos-yGoalPos)

solution = distance[initial_state.reshape(n*m)].reshape((n,m))
```

Note that there is probably a more efficient way to compute the distance (eg. using `scipy`).

Comment: Thx Jérôme, I appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately I have to do someting else now, so I'm going to have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you, Jérôme. I'm delighted by what `initPos[initial_state.reshape(n*m)] = np.arange(n*m, dtype=int)` does. That's a beautiful piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension+`numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

initial_state = np.array([[7, 2, 4], [5, 0, 6], [8, 3, 1]])
goal_state = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])

# define current coordinates in goal_state per initial_state order:
res = np.array([np.argwhere(goal_state==el)[0] for el in initial_state.flatten()])

# subtract initial_state coordinates per initial state order (which is just [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0),...])
res -= np.argwhere(goal_state+1)

# take absolute value + sum X and y coordinates:
res = np.absolute(res).sum(axis=1).reshape(3,3)
```

Generally it relies on `np.argwhere(X)` which will return multidimensional coordinates where `X` is `True` (hence this `goal_state+1` - cause `0` wouldn't be returned otherwise).

Comment: Note that the line `[np.argwhere(goal_state==el)[0] for el in initial_state.flatten()]` is not fully vectorized and have a pretty bad complexity of `O((n*m)^2)`

Comment: Not sure I understand where you take power of 2 from - I would call it `O(n^2)`. But yup - it's definitely not fully vectorized.